# cant print images with JavaScript print function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print a report which includes text and images. I am using a javascript function to invoke the print functionality. Everything works well except the images on the page do not show up in the new print window.  I have included all the CSS files with it but still my images  dont appear in the new print window. Its the same even if I dont include the CSS links.

My javascript function to print is :

```
function printfun(){
        var disp_setting = "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no,";
        disp_setting += "scrollbars=no,left=0,top=0,resizable=yes,width=900 height=650,modal=yes,";
        var content_vlue = document.getElementById('<%= tblCharts.ClientID %>').innerHTML;   
        var docprint = window.open("", "", disp_setting);
        docprint.document.write('<html><head>');
        docprint.document.write('</head>');
        docprint.document.write('<body onLoad="self.print()">');
        docprint.document.title = "";
        docprint.document.write('<link href="../style/design.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
        docprint.document.write('<link href="../App_Themes/style/graphs.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
        docprint.document.write(content_vlue);
        docprint.document.write(tblCharts);        
        docprint.document.write("</body></html>");
        docprint.document.close();
        docprint.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the images background images in the CSS? If so, the browser likely isn't set to print those by default. That'd a browser setting the user would have to change.

Comment: I'd assume they're `<img>` by the OP's statement: `"Its the same even if I dont include the CSS links."`... but I have heard stranger things on this site, it's hard to take anything for granted.

Comment: No they are no background images.. they are bargraphs and such stuff

Comment: Can you show us the innerHTML that you are grabbing to print?